# OTAのWebページからホテル名を取得するXpath

Tags: web-scraping, xpath

OTAのWebページからホテル名をXpathで取得したいのですが

```
//*[@id="property-critical-root"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h1
```

の後の記述方法がわからず困っております。

URL
https://www.agoda.com/ja-jp/imperial-hotel-osaka/hotel/osaka-jp.html?checkIn=2020-04-10&los=1&adults=1&rooms=1&cid=1829967&tag=380516ea-8641-a76e-6bc5-dbf155bef959&searchrequestid=93d7edf9-2329-481c-a2ae-ab233594985d&travellerType=4&tspTypes=16

[image: OTA(Agoda)の施設ページです]

Answer (score 0):

[`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string) にノードセットを渡すことで、XPathの評価結果が文字列になります。ノードセットが要素の場合は要素の子孫のテキストを連結したものになります。

```
string(//*[@id 略 /h1)
```

ついでですが、サイトをざっと見ると以下のようなシンプルな式で大丈夫そうです。

```
string(//h1[@data-selenium="hotel-header-name"])
```

Comment: 横からすみません．`//`は` /descendant-or-self::node()/` で全ノードをなめるためコストが高いです．`/descendant::h1[@data-selenium="hotel-header-name"]` の方が効率的ではないでしょうか？

Comment: シンプルさより実行効率を取るなら、そのとおりです。